# Destructor for HashTable

Tags: c++, hashtable, destructor

How would I properly create a destructor for my hash table? Can I just do delete[]list? I use linear probing to deal with my collisions...not sure if this is relevant for creating my destructor.

```
class Graph
{
...
 private:

vertex_node **list


Graph::Graph()
{

size = 0;
capacity = INITIAL_CAP;
list = new vertex_node *[capacity];
}


Graph::~Graph
{


}
```

Comment: Yes, you can `delete[]` list. The problem is, though, if you ever copy the Graph - e.g. by accidentally passing the object in the stack, instead of passing a reference.

Answer (score 2):

first delete single elements, then delete[] the container

```
Graph::~Graph
{
   for (int i=0; i<capacity; i++)
      if (list[i])
         delete list[i];

   delete[] list;
}
```

obligatory: consider using std::vector and/or std::shared_ptr if you can use c++11, it would be much much better